# How to add multiple markers in Gmap3?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add multiple marker in gmap3. but it can't work.
If anybody any idea how to add multiple location in gmap3 API.

```
var contactmap = {

         lat: 24.091328,
         lng: 38.037067
      };

      $('#tm-map')
         .gmap3({
            zoom: 13,
            center: contactmap,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: "shadeOfGrey",
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
               mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "shadeOfGrey"]
            }
         })

 .marker({
            position: contactmap,
            icon: 'assets/img/map-marker.gif'
         })
```

This code is view only one marker. So how can I add multiple marker in Map?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: Sorry it's not working.
it's not a google map Api okay 
it's a gmap3.net Api

Comment: https://gmap3.net/ is Google Maps API.... they even claim "Google Maps syntax".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I found the Right solution with myself so thanks to support me.

```
var locations = [
  ['Yanbu Saudi Arabia', 24.091328, 38.037067, 1],
  ['Yanbu Saudi Arabia', 24.005421, 38.197395, 2]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('tm-map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.005421, 38.197395),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

console.log(markers[0]);
```

Comment: Mh ... there is no gmap3 in your solution ... but in your question.

Answer (score 0):

create an array of markers and then push each new marker object into that array and finally pass array into your `marker()`
follow this github response https://github.com/jbdemonte/gmap3/issues/123
for any future problems refer to their github page.

```
    // this is how you create array

    var multiadress = [{latLng:[1,2],content:"abcd"},{latLng:[3,4],content:"pqr"},{latLng:[6,7],content:"kbc"}] 
    var markers = [];
    $.each(multiadress, function(key, val){

                var latLng = val.latLng

                markers.push({
                    position: latLng,
                    content: val.content
                }); 
            });




    var contactmap = {

             lat: 24.091328,
             lng: 38.037067
          };

          $('#tm-map')
             .gmap3({
                zoom: 13,
                center: contactmap,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: "shadeOfGrey",
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                   mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "shadeOfGrey"]
                }
             })

     .marker(markers)
```

accept answer if it helps you.

Comment: sorry not working 
tell me one thing where i can add multiple array of lat and lang ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass a markerList:**

```
var markers = [
    { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214 },
    { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821 },
    { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431 },
    { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027 }
    ];

    function markerSetup(markers){

      var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var icon = {
                    url: "../Content/Images/Car.png", // url
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 60), // scaled size
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                };

                // alert(markers[0].lat)
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);


                var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
                trafficLayer.setMap(map);
                // map.setMap(trafficLayer);

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var lat_lng = new Array();
                var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var data = markers[i]
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        icon: icon,
                        map: map,
                        title: data.title
                    });
                    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                    (function (marker, data) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, data);
                }
                map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
                map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
                map.setZoom(12)

            });
    }
```

It's workable code. Hope it's help you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
$('#tm-map')
     .gmap3({
        zoom: 13,
        center: contactmap,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: "shadeOfGrey",
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
           mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "shadeOfGrey"]
        }
     })
     .marker(
       {position: [51.552970, 8.560290], icon: 'assets/img/map-marker.gif'},
       {position: [51.552970, 8.560290], icon: 'assets/img/map-marker.gif'},
       {position: [51.552970, 8.560290], icon: 'assets/img/map-marker.gif'},
       {position: [51.552970, 8.560290], icon: 'assets/img/map-marker.gif'}
     )
```